# Deleting specific Rows in Gridview without losing previous data

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview

I want to create a dynamic gridview that contains rownumber, two textboxes, and a linkbutton to delete a row. At page load, the grid is created by 6 rows.

I want to hide the link button for delete for the first 4 rows only. and set the previous data when the user deletes one of the last two rows.

These are the functions I'm using for setting previous data and deleting the row.

```
private void SetInitialRows() {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;

        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));//for TextBox value 
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));//for TextBox value  
        dr = dt.NewRow();

        for(int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
        { 
            dr["RowNumber"] = i;
            dr["Column1"] = string.Empty;
            dr["Column2"] = string.Empty;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        //Store the DataTable in ViewState for future reference 
        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

        //Bind the Gridview 
        Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
        Gridview1.DataBind();
}



private void SetPreviousData() {

        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null) {

            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) {

                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) {

                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");               

                    if (i < dt.Rows.Count - 1) {

                        //Assign the value from DataTable to the TextBox 
                        box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column1"].ToString();
                        box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column2"].ToString();                  

                    }

                        rowIndex++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

protected void LinkDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)sender;
            GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)lb.NamingContainer;
            int rowID = gvRow.RowIndex;
            if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null) {

                DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 1) {
                    if (gvRow.RowIndex < dt.Rows.Count - 1) {
                        //Remove the Selected Row data
                        dt.Rows.Remove(dt.Rows[rowID]);
                    }
                }

                //Store the current data in ViewState for future reference
                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

                //Re bind the GridView for the updated data
                Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
                Gridview1.DataBind();
            }

            //Set Previous Data on Postbacks
            SetPreviousData();
        }
```

Comment: And the question is?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to copy the changed data to another DataTable. If you need to save changes or do validation, this makes it simple to do without affecting the original data.